# Searching for a DBSCAN toy example

Tags: clustering, dbscan

I  have been searching in many sources (data science books, google scholar, google and medium) but I havn't found a good example.
I'm searching for something like [that](http://mnemstudio.org/clustering-k-means-example-1.htm) just in DBSCAN.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#examples-using-sklearn-cluster-dbscan) or [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/453174/visualizing-dbscan-over-successive-iterations)?

Comment: Nope, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A step by step example of DBSCAN for teaching can be found in these lecture slides:

https://dbs.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/files/Team/eschubert/lectures/KDDClusterAnalysis17-screen.pdf#page=215

[image: DBSCAN step by step example]

The newer versions of these slides are currently not online; but I intend to make them accessible eventually.

Comment: Hi, I think these slides are great. Any chance you send me links to the other parts of this course? thanks

Comment: We appreciate you contributing your expertise! Please note that if you are the author of a paper cited in an answer, you must disclose your affiliation. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/320588 (Having the same username as the author is not sufficient; you must state that you are the author in the answer.)